# Xib could not be read archived error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.5

I'm working on `xcode 4.5`; I have two xib's, one for English and the other for Arabic. After making some changes in Arabic xib I saved it and got error:

```
Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error Group

/Users/administrator/Desktop/project/projectName/projectName/ar.lproj/MainMenu.xib: 
The document "MainMenu.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this?